# Redirect Folder but not contents IIS

Tags: iis

Possible to redirect the folder but not its contents. Example....  [www.test.com/test/](http://www.test.com/test/) this folder location gets redirected but lets say the path is to a file like [www.test.com/test/test.pdf](http://www.test.com/test/test.pdf) than no redirect takes place?

I have some permissions issues that I need to resolve but looking for a quick fix for this situation until I have time.

Appreciate anyone's feedback or ideas.

Comment: Have you looked at this?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/888325/how-to-redirect-a-url-path-in-iis or https://www.isapirewrite.com/docs/?  It's an older thread, but it looks like you can use regular expressions with ISAPI rewrite rules.